# Prevent Postback in CODED UI

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am working on WINDOWS 8 RTM , IE10
I have created a Coded ui for a list with items
clicking on an item makes a postback and its details come up in another frame 
due to this postback my Coded UI fails

how can I prevent postback on a page on which I am writing a coded ui
Also I have no access to the source code of the page, so no way to give "return false;"

Comment: Does the post back happen when you your self click on the items or is it only when Coded UI clicks on the item a post back is happening?

Comment: It might be that you just need to put a wait time?
A wait time can be set using one of these options: 
1.Playback.Wait(X)
2.Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.AllThreads;
// Your Code to select the item
Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.UIThreadOnly;
3.NewDetailControl.WaitForControlExist();
NewDetailControl.WaitForControlReady();
4.Also if you are using UIMaps you can set the UIMap to a new UIMap.